# Como se chama a alça que fica no teto do veículo onde o carona se apoia?

Tags: vocabulário

Existe um acessório opcional de segurança em formato de alça que é preso no teto de veículos automotores, próximo às portas dos passageiros. Este acessório possui um nome um tanto quanto incomum, pelo menos no sul do Brasil. Aqui ele é conhecido como *[puta merda](http://forum.renaultclube.com/index.php?/topic/2982-instala%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-pre%C3%A7os-de-al%C3%A7a-de-teto-puta-merda/)*. Ao pesquisar um pouco, descobri que no resto do Brasil é conhecido também como *[puta que pariu](https://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071023052836AAhezDe)*. Tentei procurar por um nome mais oficial e cheguei aos termos *alça de segurança*, *[alça de teto](http://veiculos.mercadolivre.com.br/acessorios/pega-m%C3%A3o-%2F-al%C3%A7a-de-teto-p%2F-gol-%28puta-que-pariu%29)* e "[pega-mão](http://veiculos.mercadolivre.com.br/acessorios/pega-m%C3%A3o-%2F-al%C3%A7a-de-teto-p%2F-gol-%28puta-que-pariu%29)".

Em se tratando da indústria automobilística acho pouco provável que haja um nome universal, já que cada fabricante pode chamá-lo de uma maneira. Mesmo assim gostaria de saber como este acessório é chamado em PT_pt. Se existirem outros nomes no Brasil, gostaria de conhecê-los também.

Comment: Aqui em Portugal, não me lembro de lhe ouvir chamar o que quer que fosse. Se me tivesse que referir à coisa, chamar-lhe-ia *alça* ou *pega*. Pelo que vi parece-me que os nomes mais criativos vêm do que as pessoas diziam quando se lhe agarravam para se segurarem em curvas apertadas?

Comment: @Jacinto, exato! O folclore diz que a origem do nome decorre das expressões gritadas pelos passageiros no momento de uma freada mais brusca, ou de uma curva mais perigosa!

Comment: Se procurar por outros nomes em lojas virtuais pode encontrar "puxador"

Comment: Pra quem tem dúvida, basta consultar no Mercado Livre e ver as diversas regiões que VENDEM o produto http://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/puta-que-pariu - No mínimo em Minas, Paraná e SP é bem comum. Variação do termo, em Santa Catarina, Mato Grosso e outros. Notem o número de páginas: http://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/puta-merda

Comment: Esta pergunta poderia abranger também a alça de segurança de painel (existentes no Fusca), e não apenas a de teto. O apelido chulo também é aplicado no caso da alça de painel: [link](https://www.jocar.com.br/MapaProduto.aspx?CDV=323&CD=258&CDG=14).

Comment: Em Minas Gerais é conhecido também como "puta merda". Isso é muito engraçado. Sempre falei puta merda.... =)

Comment: Em São Paulo (tanto capital quanto interior), chamamos de "puta que pariu" (ou simplesmente de "PQP"). Não lembro de ver alguém chamando por outro nome...

Comment: Em BH todo mundo conhece esse acessório como puta que pariu mesmo. Meu namorado carioca não conhecia o termo. Talvez não seja conhecido no Rio de Janeiro...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em Portugal, chama-se a isso uma pega de teto.

A palavra pega vem do verbo pegar, e lê-se com um e aberto: `pˈɛɡɐ`.
(Se em vez do e aberto, /é/, fosse lida com e fechado, /ê/, seria um pássaro da família dos corvos - em inglês, *magpie*. O tal que rouba coisas brilhantes.)

Comment: Pássaro... ou prostituta.

Comment: (Uma prostituta de teto? Isso sim, é pensar em grande...)

Comment: Queria dizer que provavelmente o uso mais comum de _pega_ (ê) é no sentido de prostituta.

Comment: Ok. Eu discordo, @Artefacto .

Answer (score 4):

Em ptBR sugiro que você use o termo "alça de teto" e esqueça os outros. A maioria dos brasileiros raramente se refere àquela peça e, quando o faz, chama de **"alça"** ou então "aquela alça que fica junto ao teto, para segurança". As partes de um veículo automotor geralmente têm o nome comercial desconhecido do grande público e apenas os fabricantes e vendedores de peças os conhecem. Eu não chegaria em alguma loja de auto-peças para tentar comprar uma "puta merda" ou uma "puta que pariu".  Mesmo porque duvido que os fabricantes tenham batizado a alça com esses termos chulos. Isso deve ser regionalismo e do conhecimento apenas de meia dúzia de indivíduos fora do setor automobilístico. Experimente perguntar a um leigo o que significa uma "puta merda" no que se refere a auto-peças e você verá que isso não é do conhecimento de 99.99% da população.

Comment: Entre meu círculo de conhecidos é unanimidade o uso do termo _puta merda_, inclusive foi por este motivo que criei a pergunta. Eu já liguei para uma concessionária e disse que queria colocar um destes acessórios e a atendente me compreendeu. Além disto, o fato de existirem anúncios em sites de vendas e buscadores (como o Mercado Livre e Buscapé), ou fóruns de carro (como o RenaultClube) que referenciam estes termos, que concordo são inadequados já que chulos, parecem indicar o contrário, que os termos são de amplo uso.

Comment: Se você prestar atenção, eu escrevi "regionalismos".  Ninguém do meu relacionamento aqui no Rio de Janeiro conhece esses termos. Tenho muitas décadas de vida, e já tive mais de 15 carros na minha vida e nunca ouvi falar nisso. Portanto, eu não preciso consultar nenhuma fonte.   Minhas muitas décadas de vida, sendo 45 anos como proprietário de carros, e os amigos a quem consultei antes de escrever, me permite afirmar que isso é desconhecido de 99,99% da população do Brasil. Sim, somos mais de 200 milhões de brasileiros e portanto mais de 20.000 brasileiros em algum local devem conhecer o termo.

Comment: Como muitos dos que aqui frequentam estão aprendendo português como uma língua estrangeira, sugiro que eles simplesmente ignorem esse termo.  Nada a lucrar aprendendo isso.

Comment: Acho precipitado afirmar que 99%  dos brasileiros não conhecem o termo e que estrangeiros querendo aprender a língua não devem aprendê-lo. Mas se é seu ponto de vista, Ok. Fico no aguardo de outras opiniões.

Comment: estive pensando, talvez os termos que citei sejam, além de regionalismos, utilizados por pessoas mais jovens. Conforme citei, fóruns de proprietários de automóveis, sites de venda de auto-peças e de dúvidas, todos mencionam os termos chulos, junto dos outros. Isso dá a entender que são termos de uso comum e gostaria de saber como são conhecidos em outras regiões falantes do Português.

Comment: @gmauch No meu círculo, em São Paulo, é bem comum isso ser chamado de "puta merda", em contextos informais, em diversas faixas etárias - incluindo gente mais velha que o Centaurus.